# ConcurrentBag and foreach

Tags: c#, multithreading, foreach, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I've seen ConcurrentBag and Parallel.ForEach being used in another question. Now I'm wondering if it is still thread safe if I use a regular foreach instead of Parallel.ForEach to read data from a ConcurrentBag.

Thus even though other threads are adding data to and removing data from a ConcurrentBag, I want in a specific thread to go through all items in the bag (it can even be a snapshot of that bag as it doesn't have to be 100% up-to-date) and use the data found for something else.

So my question is, is a normal foreach here doable without breaking the thread safety of the ConcurrentBag or do I HAVE to use Parallel.ForEach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your scenario, whether you're evaluating a collection with `foreach` or `Parallel.ForEach` makes no difference. This is true of a lot of things. `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't magically kick enumerators into some special thread-safe mode.

[From the fine manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381960(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ## Remarks
>
> The enumeration represents a moment-in-time snapshot of the contents of the bag. It does not reflect any updates to the collection after GetEnumerator was called. The enumerator is safe to use concurrently with reads from and writes to the bag.

Comment: does foreach automatically use the GetEnumeration method? Or do I have to do it like "foreach (MyObject current in MyConcurrentBag.GetEnumerator())" instead of "foreach (MyObject current in MyConcurrentBag)  ?

Comment: [From the fine manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6(v=vs.71).aspx) *Evaluates to a type that implements IEnumerable or a type that declares a GetEnumerator method.* Conceptually `foreach` calls `GetEnumerator` although the compiler and JIT optimiser might pull some sleights of hand along the way.

Comment: ok so it should call it tnx. (somehow I always manage to not find the things I search for in the manuals^^')